# Java error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Signal already used by VM: INT

Tags: java, jvm, signals

I am investigating a Java issue (using IBM JVM 1.4.2 64-bit) on Red Hat Linux. 
I am wondering if anyone has seen this error message before and knows if there is a workaround to this problem?

Source:

```
import sun.misc.Signal;
import sun.misc.SignalHandler;

public class SignalTest extends Thread
{
    private static Signal signal = new Signal("INT");

    private static ShutdownHandler handler = new ShutdownHandler();

    private static class ShutdownHandler implements SignalHandler
    {
        public void handle(Signal sig)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Signal.handle(signal, handler);
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException <Signal already used by VM: INT>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Signal already used by VM: INT
at
com.ibm.misc.SignalDispatcher.registerSignal(SignalDispatcher.java:145)
at sun.misc.Signal.handle(Signal.java:199)
at xxx
```

Additional Information:

I found out something strange.
The reason why it fails is because I am running the program inside a shell script as a background process.

i.e. 
sigtest.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp . SignalTest >> sigtest.log 2>&1 &
```

If I run the program from the command line, or remove the "&" (i.e. make it a foreground process inside the shell script), it doesn't have a problem...
I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: Jin, given your comment on my answer, the JVM isn't letting you register a hook on this event. Can you describe more about what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a way to do it that is more in sync with the JVM's expectation.

Comment: I want the program to exit gracefully by running up some "clean up" code if it's interrupted.

Comment: The issue was JVM specific.
I awarded the bounty to Jitter, since his answer included "JVM implementation specific" and provided the most tools for diagnosing my problem.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is may very well be a JVM implementation specific problem. We are using an undocumented / unsupported API (`sun.misc.Signal/SignalHandler`) and therefore no contract on the behavior of the API is guaranteed.

The IBM JVM implementation could do signal-handling-related-things differently from the SUN JVM implementation and thus cause this problem. So that this specific use case works in the SUN JVM but not in the IBM JVM.

But try out the following (I can't try it out myself):

Do all combinations off starting the JVM with one/two/three of those parameters and there possible value combinations.

1. the `-Xrs` option specified / not specified
2. the property `ibm.signalhandling.sigint` set to `true` / `false`
3. the property `ibm.signalhandling.rs` set to `true` / `false`

(The properties where found via google in several error dumps but I can't find any specific documentation on them)

I don't know if the IBM JVM also supports this special flag but you could try adding this too which in SUN JVM seems to be specific for some problems with signal handlers under linux/solaris

```
-XX:-AllowUserSignalHandlers
```

Or try using a native signal handler if that is an option for you. Check out the code samples provided:

- in the [link below](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling)
- [Catching SIGINT in a Java application under UNIX](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_thread/thread/bac336a1411a3b4e/b3268276845a3ca4)
- [Check signal handling, native signal chainging](http://javajiggle.com/2008/01/06/if-jni-based-application-is-crashing-check-signal-handling/)
- [JDK 6 HotSpot VM - Signal Handling on Solaris OS and Linux](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/signals.html#gbzcz)

Although it doesn't relate to your specific problem, an IBM article on JVM signal handling (slightly dated but still mostly correct). With samples for native code signal handlers:

[Revelations on Java signal handling and termination](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling)

---

But I guess this may all be to no avail as the IBM JVM implementation could rely on handling `SIGINT` itself to function correctly and thus never giving you a chance to handle `SIGINT` yourself.

Btw. from the [description to the `-Xrs` flag](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) I understand that it actually may hinder you to do what you want. It says

> When `-Xrs` is used on Sun's JVM, the
>   signal masks for SIGINT, SIGTERM,
>   SIGHUP, and SIGQUIT are not changed by
>   the JVM, and **signal handlers for these**
>   **signals are not installed**.

Or it could mean that only the JVM default actions for the signals aren't executed. Or it could depend on the JVM implementation what is really meant.

Comment: The issue was JVM specific.
I had to install another JVM to get the behaviour I desired.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting the JVM with an -Xrs option which is valid on the IBM JVM according to [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/) anyway. That might prevent the conflict.

EDIT: In response to your underlying desire, look at:

[Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

You subclass a thread object, and it will start as part of the shutdown (take out that -Xrs for this to work well). Some things (like calling halt on Runtime) can stop that from happening, so you do need to be aware of the possibility that it just won't end up happening.

Comment: That changes the output from:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException <Signal already used by VM: INT>

to the following:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException <Signal restricted by VM: INT>

Answer (score 1):

As written by [Heinz Kabutz](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue043.html), the signals you are able to catch depend on the operating system you are running on and propably the JVM version. If a certain os/jvm combination does not let you register your signal then you are out of luck. Maybe tweaking with os/vm settings might help.

According to your comment, adding a [shutdown hook](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue011.html) as proposed by Yishai should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because the VM already has a signal handler put in place for SIGINT. What you can/should do about this depends upon the context in which this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same code and it works for me. So I guess there might be some difference in the setup.

After adding

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

to the handle message I can run the class like that:

```
z@zolty:/tmp/so$ java SignalTest & sleep 1s && kill -2 $!
[1] 20467
z@zolty:/tmp/so$ Hello
z@zolty:/tmp/so$
z@zolty:/tmp/so$ java SignalTest
[1]+  Done             java SignalTest
```

Comment: Yes, I have two environments.
One is 32 bit Linux, it works fine using Sun JVM.
One is 64 bit Linux, it doesn't work on this one.

Comment: My setup is 64-bit (2.6.24...) using Sun JVM (HotSpot, 1.6.0_11).

Comment: I'm starting to feel this is less a programming issue and more a JVM issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by using a different JVM implementation (SuSE) instead of IBM.
When dealing with undocumented features, it appears that JVMs are not very consistent in behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same problem. I run the java program from a ksh script. 
If I run the script with the account which has the csh profile 
i.e., in /etc/passwd file

userx:*:7260:20::/home/userx:/usr/bin/csh

The script will run succesfully. But if I run it with account which has other than sh profile, it is giving the same error.

So, the solution is to get your unix user profile changed to csh.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this problem with the IBM JVM (64 bit) on Linux. It turned out that the JVM is sensitive to the signal mask of the process that calls it.

```
> grep Sig /proc/self/status
SigQ:   1/1030663
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000001001006
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
```

Note that the bit for SIGINT (value 2) is set in SigIgn. When starting the IBM JVM with this mask, it refuses to install a handler for SIGINT. I worked around the problem by launching the JVM through a Python wrapper that resets the SIGINT handler to the default:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import signal
import sys

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

args = sys.argv[1:]
os.execv(args[0], args)
```

The first argument to the wrapper is the `java` command, then follow the arguments for the JVM.